# How to get Element value by calling JS function in Rails Controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an element in my view and I want it's value. I can get it in a javascript file, but I need it in my controller to make a SQL query.

How do I call that JS function from my Rails controller and get the return value?

My JS file looks like this:

```
  function getAmountOrdered(){
    var amountOrdered = document.getElementById('order_amount_ordered').value;
    return amountOrdered
  }
```

and Rails controller:

```
def index
  amount_ordered = ????
  some more stuff...
end
```

What do I have to write where the ???? are?

Comment: You can simply pass the `order_amount_ordered` value in the API call to your controller method and use it in the query.

Comment: and how does that work?

Comment: you can append the query params by adding `?param_name=param_value` in the URL for your GET request.

Comment: I don't think this will work. the amount_ordered is in another form than the one I'm submitting.

Comment: @marcoHoll90 well it's your job to make the value available to your `index` action. there are 2 ways to do it: a). make sure the other form is saved and order_amount_ordered is available in backend for querying in `index` action. b). you fetch and pass `order_amount_ordered` value while calling the `index` action from frontend. there are not shortcuts here.

Comment: I **am** trying to do option b in my question, but it seems like it's not possible this way. I unfortunately don't know how else to do it and your comments don't make sense to a newbie like me